# Extract all between 3rd and 5th occurrence of forward slashes in a URL string

Tags: regex, preg-match

Using RegEx I am trying to extract everything between 3rd and 5th occurrences of forward slashed in URLs like `http://www.domain.tld/content/article/26849929.html`, that is, in this case, `content/article` part.

Later, I will be replacing them in PHP code with the new aliases like `http://www.domain.tld/newalias/26849929.html` using the following PHP command:

`preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);`

Would appreciate if someone could point out the shortest and most efficient way to me. Thanks!

Comment: Stab in the dark, here, but if you're using Apache, this is the sort of thing you'd use `mod_rewrite` for.

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following:

```
^(?:(?:[^\/]*\/){3})([^\/]*\/[^\/]*)
```

This gets the first three forward slashes, and anything that precedes them, in a non-capturing group, then whatever follows the 3rd slash plus the 4th slash plus whatever follows that up to a possible 5th slash in a capturing group.

I'm not sure this is the best way to capture what you want out of this particular string, but it is a general solution to the question.

[Please see Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xB2fK5/2) for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different ways, I've arrived to this one:

`^(?:.*?\K\/){3}(.*)(?:.*?\/)`

It works fine for me, but I am not sure if it is the best one, because it is not indicating the fifth slash (and I need all between exactly 3rd and 5th slashes). Please let me know if you know of better way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex, I'd use:

```
$str = "http://www.domain.tld/content/article/26849929.html";
$elem = explode('/', $str);
$elem[3] = 'replacement';
unset($elem[4]);
$str = implode('/', $elem);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
http://www.domain.tld/replacement/26849929.html
```